# Why is my interval starting twice?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a project where I need to preload 100+ images, but I don't want to spam the server hosting the images with 100 very short requests.

To fix this problem, I was trying to create a function that sets an interval, where each iteration preloads a single image.  When there is nothing left to load, the interval is cleared.  If the function is called again while the first interval is still running, it exits the function early.

At this point, it's a conceptual question.  Why is this snippet:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function logger() {
    var logging = false;
    var interval = {};

    function log() {
        if (ids.length) {
            console.log(ids.shift());   
        } else {
            console.log('Logging done!');
            clearInterval(interval);
            logging = false;
        }
    }

    return (function() {
        if (!logging) {
            console.log('Logging started!');
            logging = true;
            interval = setInterval(log, 250);
            return null;
        } else {
            console.log('Logging already started!');
            return null;
        }
    })()
}

//First call to logger
logger();

//Add a few more elements to ids array
ids = ids.concat([6, 7, 9, 9, 10]);

//Call logger again
logger();
```

starting the interval twice, and logging a pair of elements near simultaneously?  If you want to see the behavior of this snippet, here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/she6o220/) I made it with.

--edit--

Thanks for the help everyone :) .  I realize now that `logging` and `interval` were not being saved.  In order to save them without declaring a global variable, I just needed to make the declaration self-executing and not invoke the returned function immediately.

Comment: Because you're calling `logger()` twice which calls `setTimeout` each time...!? Maybe you're thinking that you're working around this with `var logging`, but `var logging` is a local variable which is not shared between the two separate `logger()` invocations.

Comment: The function has a flag in it, that is supposed to check if the interval is already set.  The self-executing function *should* only set the interval if the flag (logging) is false.

Comment: That's where reality diverges from your expectations. `logging` is set to `false` every time you call `logger()`. It pretty plainly says so in your code. ;-P

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now.  I'm not sure why I was expecting that the variables outside of the returned closure would be saved.

Comment: You aren't actually creating a closure because you're not returning a function.  You're returning the result of executing that inner function which returns `null` in both cases.  There is no closure created here.  Thus, each call to `logger()` just executes the same code over and over again.

Comment: @jfriend00 *Weeeeeelll...*, `log` is a closure... ;o)

Comment: Well, I figured out where I went wrong.  I meant to wrap the `logger` function in a closure to share state, and return the outer function not inside of a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and realize why I got the unexpected behavior now.  This is what I was actually going for:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var logger = (function() {
    var logging = false;
    var interval = {};

    function log() {
        if (ids.length > 0) {
            console.log(ids.shift());   
        } else {
            console.log('Logging done!');
            clearInterval(interval);
            logging = false;
        }
    }

    return function() {
        if (!logging) {
            console.log('Logging started!');
            logging = true;
            interval = setInterval(log, 250);
            return null;
        } else {
            console.log('Logging already started!');
            return null;
        }
    }
})()

//First call to logger
logger();

//Add a few more elements to ids array
ids = ids.concat([6, 7, 9, 9, 10]);

//Call lagger again
logger();
```

I just put a closure on the returned function, when I really should have wrapped the initial declaration.  Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/she6o220/2/) of the above code.

Answer (score -1):

@deceze you're right.
The var logging is inited every time you call the logger.
Just make the flag a global var.

Comment: I try not to declare global variables.  I did figure it out, though, and answered my own question.  I just had the self-executing part in the wrong place.